# Revert to original cell value in ngGrid if DB write fails

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm using ngGrid to display data sourced from a database. Using the methods described in the ngGrid documentation I am able to write changes in the grid back to my database. However, I have been     unable to find a way to revert to the original value if the db responds with a write error.

Here are the cell template and update functions i'm using:

```
var cellEditableTemplate = "<input ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" ng-input=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-model=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-blur=\"updateEntity(col, row, COL_FIELD)\" />";

$scope.updateEntity = function(column, row, cellValue){
    console.log(row.entity);
    console.log(column.field);
    console.log('Cell Value prior: ' + row.entity[column.field]);
    console.log('Cell Value after: ' + cellValue);

    //Trying to cache original value, i know this is wrong.
    var fail = row.entity[column.field];

    //row.entity[column.field] = cellValue;

    var map = {};
    map[column.field] = cellValue;

    //Code to prevent multiple ngBlur events
    //http://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/editable-nggrid-with-both-dropdowns-and-selects/
    if(!$scope.save) {
      $scope.save = {promise: null, pending: false, data: null};
    }

    $scope.save.data = map;
    if(!$scope.save.pending){
      $scope.save.pending = true;
      $scope.save.promise = $timeout(function(){
        //DB Write Function
        $scope.update(row.entity.id, $scope.save.data).then(
        function (result){
          //DB Write Success
          //Ensure new value is written to scope
          $scope.log("Table Updated", result);
          row.entity[column.field] = cellValue;
        }, function (error){
          //DB Write Failure
          //Need to revert to original value
          $scope.log("Error updating value", error);
          row.entity[column.field] = fail; //I know this doesn't work!
        });
        $scope.save.pending = false;
      }, 500);
    }
  };
```

A review of this code makes it clear that setting ng-model to COL_FIELD in the template means that every  update to the cell value is immediately applied to the scope. So what I need is a way to cache the original value before any editing happens.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your editableCellTemplate, use the ngFocus directive to call a function that caches the row:

```
ng-focus="cacheRow(row.entity)"
```

where cacheRow() looks something like this:

```
$scope.cacheRow = function(startValue) {
  $scope.rowHolder = {};
  angular.copy(startValue, $scope.rowHolder);
};
```

Then in updateEntity(), you can compare the new and old values to see if they're the same (to avoid updating unnecessarily) and also use the cached row to revert if the database update fails:

```
if (!angular.equals($scope.rowHolder, row.entity)) {
  //update here
  ...
  //on DB write fail, reset to $scope.rowHolder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler way. You can revert old value after db-write fails in gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit:

```
        $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

            gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope,function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
                if (colDef.name === 'comment' && newValue !== oldValue) {
                    var entity = new Entity();
                    entity.id = rowEntity.id;
                    entity.comment = newValue;
                    $scope.updateEntity(entity)
                        .then(function (value) {
                        },
                            function(error) {
                                rowEntity.comment = oldValue;
                                Messages.on_http_error(error);
                            });
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            });
```

};

$scope.updateEntity(entity) is your function that should return promise.